# AltBeacon library inconsistent when detecting a beacon after app has been stopped and resumed

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I have noticed that the [AltBeacon](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) library takes a while (10-15 seconds) to detect the beacon in case the app is paused and resumed multiple times.

I've recreated the error by writing a sample app in the simplest possible way. Here's the code.

**Application class**

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContext = applicationContext

        // iBeacon layout
        BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext).beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))

        // App lifecycle observer for debugging purpose
        ProcessLifecycleOwner
            .get()
            .lifecycle
            .addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                    Log.d("BeaconScanner", "App.onStart")
                }

                override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                    Log.d("BeaconScanner", "App.onStop")
                }
            })
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var appContext: Context
            private set
    }

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        // Set the range notifier
        val beaconManager: BeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(App.appContext)
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier { beacons, region ->
            Log.d("BeaconScanner", "Beacons detected: ${beacons.size}")
        }

        // Start ranging my beacon
        val id = "df4ec3a8-5380-4fc0-a217-ae2200c173dc"
        val uuid = Identifier.parse("4f0183dd-7e3e-452e-bf91-b3492b0bbf1c")
        val major = Identifier.parse("12345")
        val minor = Identifier.parse("54321")
        val region = Region(id, uuid, major, minor)
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
    }

}
```

**Logcat output while testing**

[image]

**Some additional info**

- There's no permissions code, since it's a test project I simply enabled them manually in the Settings
- If the app is killed, everything is working as expected. Problem appears when app is put in background and then later resumed
- Often, the app will stop detecting the beacon after first pause/resume. It seems to be random. Often it will survive multiple pauses.
- I am testing on Google Pixel 4, Android 12. But I have gotten reports from multiple users that the beacon detection is inconsistent like this. Two specific reports came from users using Samsung 21 Ultra and Huawei P30 PRO.

**Logcat output in debug mode**

```
2022-01-19 17:49:27.814 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: App.onStart
2022-01-19 17:49:27.827 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2022-01-19 17:49:27.828 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
2022-01-19 17:49:27.828 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
2022-01-19 17:49:27.828 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest W/JobInfo: Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
2022-01-19 17:49:27.851 8566-8668/com.mhcin.beacontest I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=11728ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=1097496, IntendedVsync=19424053119697, Vsync=19424064230808, InputEventId=2106735827, HandleInputStart=19424067797913, AnimationStart=19424067801143, PerformTraversalsStart=19424067802497, DrawStart=19424079987394, FrameDeadline=19424091841919, FrameInterval=19424067788434, FrameStartTime=11111111, SyncQueued=19424080709842, SyncStart=19424080762602, IssueDrawCommandsStart=19424080971769, SwapBuffers=19424081612394, FrameCompleted=19435781611320, DequeueBufferDuration=9896, QueueBufferDuration=430260, GpuCompleted=19435781611320, SwapBuffersCompleted=19424082285259, DisplayPresentTime=0, 
2022-01-19 17:49:27.885 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: ScanJob Lifecycle START: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@5ff449f
2022-01-19 17:49:27.890 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner
2022-01-19 17:49:27.893 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2022-01-19 17:49:27.893 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@5ff449f
2022-01-19 17:49:27.893 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: scanJob version 2.19.2 is starting up on the main process
2022-01-19 17:49:27.893 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
2022-01-19 17:49:27.896 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2022-01-19 17:49:27.896 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
2022-01-19 17:49:27.896 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-01-19 17:49:27.899 8566-8670/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis
2022-01-19 17:49:27.899 8566-8671/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-01-19 17:49:27.901 8566-8668/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=6 scannerId=-1 mScannerId=0
2022-01-19 17:49:29.002 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:30.107 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:31.211 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:32.315 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:33.418 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:34.523 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:34.525 8566-8671/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-01-19 17:49:34.528 8566-8668/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=6 scannerId=-1 mScannerId=0
2022-01-19 17:49:35.628 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:36.731 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:37.835 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:38.938 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:40.043 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:41.147 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:41.149 8566-8671/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-01-19 17:49:41.152 8566-8668/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=6 scannerId=-1 mScannerId=0
2022-01-19 17:49:42.252 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:43.356 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:44.460 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:45.562 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:46.665 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:47.771 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 0
2022-01-19 17:49:47.772 8566-8671/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-01-19 17:49:47.772 8566-8671/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
2022-01-19 17:49:47.773 8566-8671/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-01-19 17:49:47.779 8566-8668/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=9 mScannerId=0
2022-01-19 17:49:47.821 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.839 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.843 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.843 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest I/ScanHelper: Non-distinct packets detected in a single scan.  Restarting scans unecessary.
2022-01-19 17:49:47.878 8566-8679/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.878 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.898 8566-8680/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.899 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.934 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.963 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.965 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.998 8566-8681/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:47.998 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.023 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.026 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.062 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.062 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.091 8566-8681/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.093 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.119 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.122 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.153 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.155 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.186 8566-8679/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.186 8566-8681/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.212 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.215 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.247 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.247 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.273 8566-8679/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.278 8566-8681/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.303 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.308 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.333 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.337 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.369 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.369 8566-8679/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.402 8566-8680/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.403 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.461 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.463 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.496 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.524 8566-8679/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.528 8566-8680/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.557 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.562 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.588 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.596 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.618 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.626 8566-8681/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.650 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.682 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.685 8566-8682/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.710 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.715 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.741 8566-8680/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.746 8566-8678/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.775 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.775 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.805 8566-8677/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.809 8566-8676/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.843 8566-8680/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.844 8566-8681/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.870 8566-8674/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.874 8566-8675/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Cannot read device name without Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
2022-01-19 17:49:48.875 8566-8566/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconScanner: Beacons detected: 1
```

**More info**

Here's some more Logcat dump that should contain logs of `BackgroundPowerSaver` as well: https://pastebin.com/69ksApq1

I should also say that this seems to be consistently reproducible for me. It always happens after exactly 3rd time the app is paused and restarted.

Comment: Can you add `BeaconManger.setDebug(true)` and capture logs for the 10-15 seconds after app resumes where beacons are not detected?

Comment: @davidgyoung I've edited the question with Logcat output.

Comment: I can tell from the log that the core problem is that the library thinks your app is in background mode so it is using the default backgroundScanPeriod of 30 seconds: `I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis`  Based on the code you show, however, I do not think your app should be in background mode.  Do you see any log lines about `BackgroundPowerSaver`?  It should automatically switch the library between foreground and background scan periods each time your Activity comes to the foreground.

Comment: @davidgyoung I tried to get more logs for you, but my sample app suddenly doesn't detect my beacons any more. I've also just downloaded your andoid-beacon-library-reference-kotlin sample and ran it on my device, and it doesn't detect my iBeacon. I then downloaded some random "Beacon Scanner" app from Google Play store and it detects my beacons immediately and with no issues. Is it possible that there is something fundamentally wrong with the library or the way the sample app (mine and yours) is implemented? I find it really weird that AltBeacon is causing me these issues while other apps work.

Comment: @davidgyoung If you could provide any additional steps to debug my issue, I would really appreaciate it. I went through documentation multiple times and checked the `Why can I not detect beacons?` as well, and I just can't see the error. I am completely lost.

Comment: Here is a longer logcat outout with setDebug enabled. First couple of seconds after launching the app. The beacon's UUID, Major and Minor are all set to null here (so all beacons should be detected). As previously said, other general beacon scanner apps will detect it while mine won't, so I don't think it's device/beacon issue. https://pastebin.com/qyvnC6rg

Comment: I am happy to help, but the failure to detect at all is a completely different question, so you should make a new post for it.  If you make such a post I will answer in detail there.  Please note when posting the question that your logs are showing a `2022-01-24 13:59:47.015 24230-24230/com.mhcin.beacontest E/ScanHelper: SecurityException making Android O background scanner` which suggests you have not granted your app the necessary permissions (Location or Bluetooth Scan depending on Android version) to scan for beacons.

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks, I have posted another question. Hopefully we can solve that one first, and then on to this one :)

Comment: @davidgyoung After getting my sample app to work again, I've added some more info to this question. You should be able to see a bigger Logcat dump with `BackgroundPowerSaver` as well.

Comment: Reviewing the longer log, I see that. BackgroundPowerSaver appears to be working normally.  It switches the library to background mode when the activity is paused `BackgroundPowerSaver: activity paused` and takes it out of background mode when the activity is resumed `BackgroundPowerSaver: activity resumed`.  I do see that there are no beacon detections while the app is in the foreground, but logs indicate it is only in the foreground for two seconds -- too short of a time to reliably get a detection.

Comment: Understand that in the background, the library's default behavior is to scan for 30 seconds every ~15 minutes and in the foreground it scans constantly.  So if you app is in the background, you should expect that detections may have long delays.  In the foreground, detections should be faster, but only two seconds of foreground scanning may not be enough to detect a beacon.

Comment: @davidgyoung The reason logs indicate it's only in foreground for about 2 seconds is because I wanted to keep them short, but the beacon was not detected for about 15-20 seconds after, just like in the example in the original question. After adding `beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)` to my code, I can no longer reproduce this error. Beacon is detected within a second after each app resume, no matter how many times I pause and resume the app.

Comment: However this is probably not the best solution, since I understand calling this method might prevent background scanning from functioning correctly.

Comment: Understood about the short logs.  Ok, so in this case the logs indicate a formal Android BLE scan is started properly after returning from the background and there are no library errors, yet detections do not come in immediately (for at least two seconds in the case of this log).  This is not expected Android behavior and I do not see this on my reference Pixel devices.  Could this be an OEM-specific problem?  What model and OS version is this?  Also, do you see any system level error messages in LogCat when the scan is started when going out of background mode?

Comment: The reason the intent scan strategy might be helping is because the library starts a single scan and does not restart when the app returns to the foreground.  This may be an ok workaround for your use case but it would be nice to understand the cause of the problem you report:  What is delaying scan starts for you on return to foreground?

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the variable

```
var beaconTrackingManager: BeaconTrackingManager = BeaconTrackingManager()
```

When required to scan

```
try {
     beaconTrackingManager.startScanning()
} catch (e: Exception) {
     e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Call stop scan in onDestroy either from activity, service or in which context you have been used.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    try {
        beaconTrackingManager.stopScanning()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```