# AltBeacon library won't detect iBeacon

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I am trying to detect an iBeacon with AltBeacon library but it won't work.

iBeacon layout is registered:

```
BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext).beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))
```

Ranging code

```
val beaconManager: BeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(App.appContext)
beaconManager.addRangeNotifier { beacons, region ->
    Log.d("BeaconScanner", "Beacons detected: ${beacons.size}")
}

// Start ranging my beacon
val id = "test"
val uuid = Identifier.parse("30168DC2-8CA6-4283-8169-B309262C4561")
val major = Identifier.parse("12345")
val minor = Identifier.parse("54321")
val region = Region(id, uuid, major, minor)
Log.d("BeaconScanner", "Started ranging $region")
beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
```

The beacon seems to be detected, but the library thinks the Regions does not match

```
Beacon packet detected for: id1: 30168dc2-8ca6-4283-8169-b309262c4561 id2: 12345 id3: 54321 with rssi -42
2022-01-24 16:31:43.578 14239-14276/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: beacon detected : id1: 30168dc2-8ca6-4283-8169-b309262c4561 id2: 12345 id3: 54321
2022-01-24 16:31:43.578 14239-14275/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: Beacon packet detected for: id1: 30168dc2-8ca6-4283-8169-b309262c4561 id2: 12345 id3: 54321 with rssi -42
2022-01-24 16:31:43.578 14239-14275/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: beacon detected : id1: 30168dc2-8ca6-4283-8169-b309262c4561 id2: 12345 id3: 54321
2022-01-24 16:31:43.579 14239-14275/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
2022-01-24 16:31:43.579 14239-14275/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: This region (id1: 80ddda3d-66b7-4e35-bf6a-8a647f43126c id2: 12345 id3: 54321) does not match beacon: id1: 30168dc2-8ca6-4283-8169-b309262c4561 id2: 12345 id3: 54321
2022-01-24 16:31:43.579 14239-14276/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
2022-01-24 16:31:43.580 14239-14276/com.mhcin.beacontest D/ScanHelper: This region (id1: 80ddda3d-66b7-4e35-bf6a-8a647f43126c id2: 12345 id3: 54321) does not match beacon: id1: 30168dc2-8ca6-4283-8169-b309262c4561 id2: 12345 id3: 54321
2022-01-24 16:31:43.597 14239-14239/com.mhcin.beacontest D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: got record
2022-01-24 16:31:43.598 14239-14273/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002784495beaac2372a367ef2729772d9728b120dcf6284c200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 30
2022-01-24 16:31:43.599 14239-14273/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002784495beaac2372a367ef2729772d9728b120dcf6284c200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2022-01-24 16:31:43.599 14239-14273/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002784495beaac2372a367ef2729772d9728b120dcf6284c200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 30
2022-01-24 16:31:43.599 14239-14273/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002784495beaac2372a367ef2729772d9728b120dcf6284c200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2022-01-24 16:31:43.607 14239-14239/com.mhcin.beacontest D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: got record
2022-01-24 16:31:43.607 14239-14278/com.mhcin.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
```

Looking at the logs, it seems to me like AltBeacon is looking for the wrong Region? It clearly says it finds my iBeacon, but then it's looking to match a region with a completely different UUID even though my code clearly defines the correct UUID.

Whole LogCat dump here: https://pastebin.com/VHCkd6Kx

Comment: Are you sure that code to start ranging is actually executing?  I would add a debug line and look for it to be sure.  Have you ever told the library to look for that UUID starting with 80ddda3d?  If you have previously told the library to monitor for that region it will continue to do so forever until you tell it to stop, as the monitored regions are saved to persistent phone storage (by default).

Comment: @davidgyoung Ahh I see the issue! Yes, the code was definitely being called. My issue was that while I changed iBeacon UUID, I never changed the uniqueId, the first parameter of `Region`. If I change my simulated iBeacon UUID and restart the app, it won't detect it, as it will keep looking for the old one. Once I change the uniqueId as well, it works. I kept checking `beaconManager.rangedRegions` as well and it always contained the one I wanted to range. Also, it seems that this survived app reinstall. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: I'd expect if I start ranging a Region with same uniqueId as previous one but updated UUID, Major or Minor, it should probably replace the old one.

Comment: Ranged regions are not persisted.  The library is designed to behave as you desire, not as you reported In this question. I have done lots of work with this and have not seen this behavior, so there must be some other factor.  Perhaps your code was not being restarted?  Sometimes Android sudio tries to partially launch an app (just the activity) without installing the application itself.

Comment: Got it, I will do some more testing on this tomorrow and I'll let you know if I figure out the exact issue.

Comment: @davidgyoung After more testing and trying, I simply can't recreate my issue any other way. The ID seems to be the culprit from my perspective. Not trying to prove you wrong, I just want to understand the issue. Please see the video attached: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgZuK2A54oU On first app launch, you'll see beacon is detected. After I change the UUID, you will see that the next two launches won't detect the beacon. After I change the ID, it is detected again. If I make the ID random, it will detect it immediately. As you see I always fully stop and launch the app between tests.

Comment: I have reviewed your video and it does appear that you are restarting the app each time.  I tried to reproduce this with the official library reference app [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin) but I cannot reproduce.  When I try, I simply change the Region definition [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/BeaconReferenceApplication.kt#L77) keeping the unique id parameter the same, and re-run the app.  When the identifier matches, I detect a beacon.

Comment: I cannot explain what you see, but I cannot reproduce with the reference app.  If you can give me steps to reproduce with the reference app I will investigate further.

Comment: @davidgyoung I have managed to reproduce the issue with the reference app by commenting out lines 64, 65, 66 and 67 [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin/blob/f07262e489c8286d83f1ae62b025fe081d594a56/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/BeaconReferenceApplication.kt#L64). Although I believe the main culprit is `beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)`. After I added that line to my own sample project, the issue from my other question seemed to disappear as well.

Comment: You might need to try it a couple of times though. I notice when `beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)` is absent, the beacon detection seems to be a lot less consistent in general and my issues are easier to reproduce, but not 100% of the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: I also want to point out that my device could be at play here. At some point during testing, it completely lost the ability to detect beacons and the only thing that helped was to restart the device. However, adding the line I mentioned above did seems to help [my other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70771171/2454356) as I can no longer reproduce it, no matter how many times I pause/resume the app, while it was consistently reproducible before.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the way beacon scanning Regions are persisted in the Android Beacon Library.  The problem generally only applies to monitoring regions, but when using the job scheduler for scanning (`beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(true)`) it applies to ranged regions as well.

The solution is to do one of three things:

1. Any time you change the identifiers you are ranging or monitoring, also change the unique ID of the region.
2. Any time you change the identifiers you are rating or monitoring, also change the unique ID of the region, add code first to explicitly call `stopMonitoring` or `stopRanging` on the old region definition.
3. Uninstall and reinstall your app to clear out persistence.

This is admittedly awkward.  You can see a detailed description of the problem in the library's open source repo along with proposals on making it better:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/1075

Any ideas on making this better are appreciated.  Please comment on the above issue if you have thoughts.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answering this question. I'm sorry for being unresponsive, but I had no more allocated time to this issue and the workaround I mentioned above had to do for now. I still have a task to research this in the near future, so I will take my time to check out the issue you linked and see if I can help in any other way.